# What's the difference between two ways of adding property to an existing js object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Let's say we need to add a property to an existing js object

```
var billingData = {}
```

In my case, I want to store input value in the js object
Here's the basic input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="billingFullName">
```

We, basically, have two ways to add the property to the js object:
The first one:

```
billingData["billingFullName"] = document.getElementById('billingFullName').value
```

And the second one:

```
billingData.billingFullName = document.getElementById('billingFullName').value
```

What's the difference between them?
I'm asking, because when I was submitting the js object using AJAX to MVC Controller, where properties where added using the `[]` notation, the model in the Controller appeared to be null. Whereas, the dot notation appeared to solve the issue and I'm wondering why..

Comment: There is no difference if you are using these strings.. Bracket notation is if you want to use a variable as the property name or you have a property name that will not be syntactically correct as dot notation, e.g., if there is a space of a plus sign, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you use bracket notation when you need to define a property dynamically such as with a variable or if the key is not in proper format for dot notation:

```
const obj = {}
const someKey = 'key'
obj[someKey] = 'somevalue'

console.log(obj.key) // 'somevalue' 
console.log(obj.someKey) // undefined
```

Dot notation is when you already know the key:

```
const obj = {}
object.key = 'someValue'
```